# Typescript Constructor Class not behaving as expected, "0 Arguments Expected"

Tags: typescript

I have a constructor class, it should take in two numbers as arguments and build an object with two props and a single method.

```
export class Context{
    public input1: number;
    public input2: number;

    Constructor(num1: number, num2: number) {
        this.input1 = num1; 
        this.input2 = num2;
    }

    display() {
        console.log(this.input1, this.input2); 
    }
}
```

I instantiate the class, and attempt to pass in two values as arguments as follows:

```
import { Context } from "./context";

class App {
    public static main() {
        let context: Context = new Context(2,7); 
        context.display();
    }
}

App.main();
```

However, my IDE is stating that the new Context call for instantiation does not expect any arguments to be passed into it, this is not correct and I do not understand why I am receiving this error.

Thanks

Comment: Why does your `Constructor` have an uppercase `C`? Try `constructor`

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because register is important.

`Constructor` from capital `C` is not recognized as class constructor function, I think it is treated as a method.

Therefore, there is no constructor defined for the `Context` class, so you reasonably getting an error... Just rename `Constructor` to `constructor`...